# Cannot get powerApps to work with SharePoint List

Tags: list, powerapp

unfortunately, Microsoft will not support the Access App anymore next March. So, I decided to try Power apps. I tried this [tutorial](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/getting-started/) by Microsoft and Saw caution signs to the left of the *Search Item* box. I went to the formula bar and hovered over *TextSearchBox1* and got this message.

> The requested operation is invalid. Server Response: The query to field 'pROJECT/LinkTitleNoMenu' is not valid

This is what my screen looks like.

[image]

My question is why Am I getting that error stated above? How am I getting an error message already if I did not do anything to the App yet? Is there an issue with the connection with the SharePoint List or is it some other error that is causing this issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve? and can you update what tutorial you are referring?

Comment: You have a lookup from one list to another. When you do that lookup, remove the name with presence.

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti  I just trying to sync a SharePoint list to a powerapp. When I try to sync them together I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had added a **new lookup column** and suddenly the app stopped working. It was enough to **remove** the newly create column from the list and the app started again working.
By the way, I have other lookup columns and have **no problem** with them. Maybe PA does not like if you add new lookup columns after you created the app...